# Static Text in flutter not showing

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-text

I put my all labels in `AppLabels` class and fetching. In debug mode during development its work fine but when I run `"flutter build apk --release"`  and run the app, all the labels not showing in my app.

and I am showing Text by using `AppLabels.mytext`

and my result APK shows like this with no text

This is my main class code:

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  LocationPermission locationPermission = Get.put(LocationPermission());
  @override
  void initState() {
    locationPermission.getlocation();

    super.initState();
  }

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Sizer(builder: (context, orientation, deviceType) {
      return GetMaterialApp(home: GettingStarted());
      // home: Home(),
    });
  }
}
```

and this is my app Labels class code:

```
class AppLabels {
  static String gpsNavigation = "GPS Navigation";
  static String getStarted = "Get Started";
  static String allYouNeed =
      "All you need is the plan, the road map, and \n the courage to press on to your destination.";
  static String gettingStarted = "Get Started  >";
  static String agree = 'Agree ';
  static String termsOfServices = 'Terms of Services';
}
```

and I am using that labels in my app like this

```
    // ignore_for_file: prefer_const_constructors

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:navigation_project/Constants/app_colors.dart';
import 'package:navigation_project/Constants/app_images.dart';
import 'package:navigation_project/Constants/app_labels.dart';
import 'package:navigation_project/Constants/app_text_style.dart';
import 'package:sizer/sizer.dart';

import 'main_tabs_screen.dart';

class GettingStarted extends StatelessWidget {
  const GettingStarted({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 50.h,
            width: 60.w,
            child: Image.asset(
              AppImages.papermap,
              // fit: BoxFit,
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.w, right: 5.w),
            child: Text(
              AppLabels.gpsNavigation,
              style: AppTextStyle.poopinsRegularBlack33,
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 2.0.h, left: 5.w, right: 5.w),
            child: Text(
              AppLabels.allYouNeed,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: AppTextStyle.poopinsRegularBlack12,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 10.h),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Get.to(() => MainTabPage());
            },
            child: Text(
              AppLabels.getStarted,
              style: AppTextStyle.poopinsRegularBlack14
                  .copyWith(color: AppColors.kwhite),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 8.h),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Radio(value: 0, groupValue: 0, onChanged: (a) {}),
              Text.rich(TextSpan(children: <InlineSpan>[
                TextSpan(
                  text: AppLabels.agree,
                  style: AppTextStyle.poopinsRegularBlack11,
                ),
                TextSpan(
                  text: AppLabels.privacyPolicy,
                  style: AppTextStyle.poopinsRegularBlue11
                      .copyWith(decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
                ),
                TextSpan(
                  text: ' & ',
                  style: AppTextStyle.poopinsRegularBlack11,
                ),
                TextSpan(
                  text: AppLabels.termsOfServices,
                  style: AppTextStyle.poopinsRegularBlue11
                      .copyWith(decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
                )
              ])),
            ],
          ),
        ]));
  }
}
```

Result in debug mode during development:

[image: Result during development]

Result after running `flutter build apk --release` :

[image: After apk build]

White spaces contain text, but there is no text in

Comment: can you please share the code that you have tried?

Comment: SizedBox(
            height: 50.h,
            width: 60.w,
            child: Image.asset(
              AppImages.papermap,
              // fit: BoxFit,
            ),

Comment: Can you update the question?

Comment: thats how i am using this in my project , as code is too long and characters limit thats why i am facing issue with sharing

Comment: @YeasinSheikh do you mean with proper code?

Comment: Yes the class and how you've used on code,

Comment: There is no `allYouNeed` on  `AppLabels`

Comment: i posted a short code as a project is too big and more the 200 labels there, to give you idea that how i am using this code

Comment: all the labels are added in AppLabels class

Comment: Consider updating the question that include `allYouNeed `

Comment: @YeasinSheikh all done

Comment: @MubashirNawaz: You should use `const` for the label =>  `static const yourLabel = "labelValue";`.

From your code, I think you're trying to reinventing localizations. Try learning https://docs.flutter.dev/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization instead. Use https://github.com/flutter/website/tree/archived-master/examples/internationalization/gen_l10n_example for your learning tool.

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך i tried with  `const` but same result, i am not  using internalization , just make a class of AppLabels to collect all the text at one place

Comment: Your problem shouldn't happened normally. Perhaps it is a bug because of using `get` library? Have you tried your app without using that library?

Comment: Your problem shouldn't happened normally. Perhaps it is a bug because of using `get` library? Have you tried your app without using that library?